# Reserve cards and winning

Tags: splendor

Can you have cards on reserve and still win if you reach 15 points? We have had arguments that a person cannot win using gold coins if cards still on reserve and not yet purchased. Some players feel that there should be a penalty at the end for having unused reserve cards.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the rules that prevent you from winning based on certain conditions and getting 15 points just triggers the end of the game. Once the final round is done the player with the most points will win regardless of how many reserve cards they may have.

[Rules](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7f/91/ba-splendor-rulebook.pdf)

Reserve a development card

> To reserve a card, a player simply needs to take a face-up
>   development from the middle of the table or (if you’re feeling
>   lucky) draw the first card from one of the three decks (level
>   ; ; ) without showing it to the other players.
>   The reserved cards are kept in hand and cannot be discarded.
>   Players may not have more than three reserved cards in hand,
>   and the only way to get rid of a card is to buy it (see below).
>   Reserving a card is also the only way to get a gold token
>   (joker). If there is no gold left, you can still reserve a card, but
>   you won’t get any gold.

END OF THE GAME

> When a player reaches 15 prestige points, complete the
>   current round so that each player has played the same number
>   of turns.
>   The player who then has the highest number of prestige points
>   is declared the winner (don’t forget to count your nobles).
>   In case of a tie, the player who has purchased the fewest
>   development cards wins.

As a note this is how the ios app works

Comment: As a strategy note, it is often the right move to reserve a card that you have no intention of ever being able to afford; to prevent another player from getting it.

Comment: @GendoIkari That is a useful tactic indeed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, I think that having unused development cards on reserve does weaken the strategy required. We may institute a rule for ourselves that the winner cannot have development cards on reserve and an extra turn will be required to discard each card on reserve. This does still allow the strategy to keep another player from getting the card but does not allow recklessly keeping cards on reserve.

Comment: @Charles Out of interest what makes you think there should be a penalty when its legal an in the rules to reserve cards you don't need to stop others getting them.  the rules also go someway to preventing 'reckless' reserving as players have a hand limit of 3 so they can not reserve cards indefinitely.